# The Four Fours puzzle using only $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, $\sqrt{}$, and concatenation. Can we make $19$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I know the classic [Four Fours puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours), which asks to create whole numbers using exactly four "$4$"s combined via certain operations (arithmetic, concatenation, grouping, factorials, etc.), the exact roster of which can vary.

I have tried this specific version of it:
You can use only the basic arithmetic operations ($\times \div + - $), square root ($\sqrt{}$), and concatenation (eg, "$44$" is allowed).

> How far you can go? I cannot go further than $18$. I am stuck with $19$ and does not seem that there is a solution for it.

Comment: I think you were saying that all four of $\times \div + -$ are allowed, and I tried to fix the formatting in your message.  Please let me know if that was wrong.

Comment: Can you also explain the challenge itself? I'll be useful for those who don't know the problem.

Comment: The puzzle is to produce an arithmetic expression, including only the six given operators, and exactly four uses of the constant $4$, whose value is exactly $19$.

Comment: Thus $1 = 4 - 4 + 4 \div 4, \quad 2 = 4 \div 4 + 4 \div 4, \quad \dots, \quad 19 = ?$

Comment: Can you clarify that the parentheses are allowed? Any by concatenation, do you allow to use it as a binary operator ($4\#\sqrt{2} = 4\#2 = 42$ is allowed), or can you just concatenate starting digits ($44,444,4444$) ?

Comment: (Assuming parentheses are allowed). If you allow concatenation as a binary operator on all strictly positive integers, then all numbers up to and including $32$ are possible, where $33$ is the smallest that is not possible. If you don't allow concatenation as a binary operator (only allow $44,444,4444$) then $19$ is indeed the smallest number that is not possible. [I've computed all possibilities]

Comment: This is what we tried. <br>
$$(4 + (4 -.4)) ÷ .4 = 19$$

Comment: The question is quite clear on what is permissible. This use of a decimal point is not included.

Comment: What's the value of $(\sqrt {\sqrt {4}}) \# 4$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\#$ denote concatenation. That is, $4\#3 = 43$. Then

$$(4 \# \sqrt 4) / \sqrt 4 - \sqrt4 = 42 / 2 - 2 = 19.$$

Not sure if you can use parentheses, but you would just have to perform concatenation first above all else.

Comment: This is patently not concatenation.

Comment: What do you mean? Concatenation in, say programming, has a similar definition: "a" + "b" = "ab" in Java, python, and probably other languages.